# How to push a route via tap0

Tags: openvpn

I need to push extra routes to my OpenVPN clients. I tried to do this in the server configuration via

```
push "route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0"
```

expecting to get on the client a route via `tap0`. What I got instead is an error during the startup:

```
Fri Jul 15 10:58:24 2016 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Fri Jul 15 10:58:24 2016 /sbin/ip route add 10.10.10.0/24 via 10.20.1.0
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

The IP address assigned to `tap0` is `10.01.10.1`, the gateway (on the other side of the tunnel) is `10.10.10.254`. This route request is therefore wrong, it should have been

```
/sbin/ip route add 10.10.10.0/24 via tap0
```

or

```
/sbin/ip route add 10.10.10.0/24 via 10.10.10.1
```

**Question 1: how was `10.20.1.0` calculated? Can I influence this calculation?**

I could use in the config file

```
push "route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.1"
```

(it works) but I may not know that `10.10.10.1` is the right IP. What I know however that the right device will be `tap0`.

**Question 2: is there a way to influence the `ip` command ran during the initialization of the client and pass the device (`tap0` in my case) to the command?**

---

*Please note that the ports are different on the client and the server - this is normal, they are DNATed*

Configuration of the server

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tap0
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh /etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server-bridge 10.20.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.20.1.2 10.20.1.200
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/static
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

---

configuration of the client

```
client
dev tap
proto udp
remote myserver.example.com 1195
resolv-retry infinite
ping-restart 15
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEgDCCA2igAwIBAgIJAN68kwhTAMwRMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGGMQswCQYD
(...)
b4yiCAmaA8p5JRYqYBiT/fUNX6akBik2M8unm+okpdkfrP6gtzGNqv9S8cwEv0b8
p20oZw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
Certificate:
    Data:
(...)
tQTcGs5BiRmx9FcRcD7MIVO9bq1rso8T7UO5rTUilBkdo9r+QVuzwFFOSMuwrUBX
l8RQ8Q==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQCYerZMSOsMjMVV
(...)
T76lH6/nsJMaRzYUBmEZU8g=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
```

Comment: I personally need configs to help.